# Cómo cambiar el nombre de un modelo en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, modelos

Tengo **Laravel 8.17.2**, y me equivoqué en el nombre del modelo de una tabla, por ejemplo en vez de nombrarla User, la nombré Uesr en la creación del  modelo, controlador y request. Mi pregunta es si hay algún comando para cambiarlo, ya que intenté hacerlo manualmente (editando todo lo necesario), pero me volvía a crear las clases Uesr, UesrController y UesrRequest.
Las cree de la siguiente manera:

```
php artisan make:model Uesr -c
php artisan make:request UesrRequest
```

Comment: Visual Studio Code y Putty @BetaM

Comment: Verifica si tiene alguna opción como PHPStorm para renombrar clases

Comment: Cómo es eso que te vuelve a crear las clases? Qué ejecutas que gatilla esa recreación? (@BetaM VSCode no tiene esa funcionalidad para PHP. Se puede hacer con la versión pro del plugin intelephense)

Comment: @ffflabs gracias por la aclaración

Comment: Al renombrar manualmente el archivo y la clase, cuando hacía alguna modificación no se guardaba, ya que se volvía a crear el archivo con el nombre antiguo. No se a que se deba, estoy trabajando en un servidor remoto. Al final opté por eliminar los archivos y volver a ejecutar los comandos correctamente.